Determinant of a special quadratic form
Consider two column vectors $\textbf{a}$ and $\textbf{b}$ of length $k$ and $m$ respectively, $km$ variables denoted $y_{i,j}$ (i=1 to k, j=1 to m), and a quadratic form $\textbf{y}^{T}\mathbb{M}\textbf{y}$ where $$\mathbb{M}=\mathbb{D}_{1/a}\otimes\mathbb{D}_{1/b}+t(\textbf{1}_{k}\textbf{1}_{k}^{T}\otimes\mathbb{D}_{1/b}+\mathbb{D}_{1/a}\otimes\textbf{1}_{m}\textbf{1}_{m}^{T})$$with $\mathbb{D}_{1/a}$ being a k by k main-diagonal matrix with $1/a_i$ on the main digagonal and analogously with $\mathbb{D}_{1/b}$, while $\textbf{1}_k$ is a column vector of lenght $k$ with all elements equal to $1$ (analogously for $\textbf{1}_m$). Using results of my inquiry "Prove a special determinant formula" one can show that the determinant of $\mathbb{M}$ is
$$(1+t*\textbf{b}^T\textbf{1}_m)^{k-1}(1+t*\textbf{a}^T\textbf{1}_k)^{m-1}(1+t*(\textbf{a}^T\textbf{1}_k+\textbf{b}^T\textbf{1}_m))/(\prod{a_i})^{m}/(\prod{b_j
})^k$$
My new question is: suppose we replace  $y_{k,m}$ (the last of our variables) by minus the sum of all the remaining $y_{i,j}$'s; we get a new quadratic form in the remaining $km-1$ variables. How does one prove that the determinant of the new ($km-1$ by $km-1$) matrix of coefficients is
$$(1+t*\textbf{b}^T\textbf{1}_m)^{k-1}(1+t*\textbf{a}^T\textbf{1}_k)^{m-1}(\textbf{a}^T\textbf{1}_k)(\textbf{b}^T\textbf{1}_m)/(\prod{a_i})^{m}/(\prod{b_j
})^k$$

Now posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/484092/special-determinant-formula
